# What is the Best Framework for HTML 5 Based Mobile Development?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, mobile, sencha-touch

What is the best framework for HTML 5 based mobile development?

I evaluated a few frameworks like jQuery Mobile , Sencha Touch , but didn't find any framework which extends its components in the mobile version as it does on the desktop version.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You could build these sencha and jQM apps in phonegap

Answer (score 28):

If you want to build a **mobile-only** site, I think the best html5 frameworks are:
[jQuery mobile + PhoneGap](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt0)
[Sencha Touch  + PhoneGap](http://www.sencha.com/learn/a-sencha-touch-mvc-application-with-phonegap/)

If you want to build a website that **adapts** for mobiles, tablets and desktop computers use  [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/), [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/), [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/download.php), [Skeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com/) or [Blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/)

Comment: I checked Sencha Touch and jQuery mobile , i was not able to find any basic features like Grid with horizontal scroll , thats to my surprise..

Comment: Perfect suggestions. Even if there is a universe of possibilities, those are the most popular. There is a lot of documentation and a very active community for those technologies.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest going for [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/), [Zurb Foundation V 4](http://foundation.zurb.com/), or [skeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com/) as the most ideal frameworks with HTML5 for mobile development.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use jQuery mobile/other frameworks with [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) like - [this](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/phonegap.html)